# Is it UB to compare pointers casted from integers?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, standards, undefined-behavior

```c
#define POINTER_TO_SOMETHING ((int*)(0x80000000))
#define BAD_POINTER ((int*)(0x12345678))

int *p = some_condition ? POINTER_TO_SOMETHING + 42 : BAD_POINTER;
if (p == BAD_POINTER) { ... }
```

Does this code have any undefined behavior or just implementation-defined behaviors?

If it helps -- the code runs in kernel mode managing page tables and others, and 0x80000000 plus the next 4KB is already registered in the page table, but I guess these hardware-specific information are irrelevant to a behavior being undefined or not, which is something C-specific.

==EDIT==
I know it's UB to compare *relationally* if invaild pointer is involved:

```
6.5.8 Relational operators

shift-expression
relational-expression < shift-expression
relational-expression > shift-expression
relational-expression <= shift-expression
relational-expression >= shift-expression

When two pointers are compared, ...
In all other cases, the behavior is undefined. ...
```

But I find no such requirement for *equality* tests.

Converting to `uintptr_t` might reduce ambiguity, but that's not the question.

Comment: It's not UB to compare arbitrary `uintptr_t` though, right?

Comment: I removed the C++ tag. One language per question please. Though in this specific case I believe C and C++ behave identically.

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. The rules are different in the different languages, and future users searching for answers for one language may be disappointed to find answers for the other. Pick one tag and delete the other. To ask about both languages, enter separate questions (which may refer to each other via links).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen "compare" might be ambiguous. Please check the edit.

Comment: We have seen hardware with segmented memory or with dedicated address registers, where *loading* an invalid address would trap. I doubt that C would say that it must work anyway.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: In C++, as in C, there are restrictions on for which operands the results of the relational operators, `<`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` are fully specified. They include not only arrays but also other objects (e.g., an earlier-declared non-static structure member has an address “less than” a later-declared non-static member). The equality operators, `==` and `!=` are more broadly specified. The addresses of unrelated objects may be compared for equality, and the result is specified.

Comment: OT: `(int*)(0x80000000)` may cause UB where `sizeof(int*)*CHAR_BIT<32` (not sure about systems where `sizeof(int*)*CHAR_BIT>=32`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the code, there are some things you could expect to be UB:

```cpp
// (1) conversion of integer to pointer is implementation-defined
#define POINTER_TO_SOMETHING ((int*)(0x80000000))
#define BAD_POINTER ((int*)(0x12345678))

// (2) addition of 42 onto pointer is only allowed when this addition
// advances the pointer within an array, otherwise UB
int *p = some_condition ? POINTER_TO_SOMETHING + 42 : BAD_POINTER;

// (3) equality comparison between pointers is never UB
if (p == BAD_POINTER) { ... }
```

It's impossible to tell whether this code contains UB without consulting the manual of your compiler. In general, the mapping from integers to pointers is implementation-defined. It's possible that `POINTER_TO_SOMETHING` is always considered to be a pointer to an almost infinitely large arrays by the compiler, in which case `POINTER_TO_SOMETHING + 42` is safe. Otherwise, it may contain undefined behavior, because the `+` operator can only advance a pointer within an array.

Unfortunately, even though integer to pointer conversions are implementation-defined behavior, and implementation-defined behavior must be documented by the compiler, GCC doesn't say much about it:

> A cast from integer to pointer discards most-significant bits if the pointer representation is smaller than the integer type, extends according to the signedness of the integer type if the pointer representation is larger than the integer type, otherwise the bits are unchanged.

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html

From this, we can see that GCC considers the mapping to be a bit-cast which possibly sign-extends, but nothing is said about what GCC thinks the pointer points to.

#### Definition of behavior for cases (1), (2), (3)

###### (1) Integer to pointer conversion

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is
> implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
> type, and might produce an indeterminate representation when stored into an object

- [C23 6.3.2.3 p5](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#6.3.2.3p5)

###### (2) Addition of integers onto pointers

> [...] If the pointer operand and the result do not point
> to elements of the same array object or one past the last element of the array object, the behavior is
> undefined. [...]

- [C23 6.5.6 p9](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#6.5.6p9)

###### (3) Equality comparison between pointers

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object
> (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to
> one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array
> object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately
> follow the first array object in the address space.

- [C23 6.5.9 p7](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#6.5.9p7)

###### (4) Relational comparison between pointers

The rules for `<=`, `>`, etc. are different compared to equality comparison. This is UB if the pointers don't point to within the same object or array.

- [C23 6.5.8 p6](https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#6.5.8p6)

Comment: You shouldn't be quoting an old draft of C23. It's not yet released and has lots of errors not yet fixed even in the latest draft.

Comment: @Lundin I don't have any more recent working draft in HTML form. Still, these sections are unlikely to change substantially, and it's more relevant than a C17 quote. The wording might change, but no proposal has made major changes to the semantics here, pretty sure it's been more or less the same since C89.

Comment: @nielsen it wouldn't. The mapping of the integer onto the pointer is implementation-defined and cannot be UB. However, the pointer produced by this conversion isn't necessarily "blessed". It's possible that dereferencing or adding onto it is UB.

Comment: @nielsen it doesn't. For example, if the pointer produced by the conversion has type `int*`  but doesn't point to an `int` at all (and (1) allows for that), then `ptr + 42` is UB. The conversion itself is fine, later use of the result might not be. In other words, (1) is never UB, but using the result as in (2) can be UB.

Comment: @JanSchultke There isn't any explicitly defined array of any type anywhere, but a 4KB page starting from 0x80000000 is registered in the page table. Could one do `p + 42` in this context?

Comment: @SylvainHubert *technically* GCC doesn't say explicitly that you can. In practice, compilers consider pointers created from integers to be somewhat blessed, and adding `+ 42` works as expected. If you're creating pointers from integers, you probably know what you're doing and don't want the compiler to violate your intent by optimizing things out. On a side note, it's better to use `volatile`, if you're working with memory mapping etc.

Comment: @SylvainHubert You are probably already aware of it, but just in case: since `p` is an `int *`, adding 42 to it should add `42 * sizeof(int)` to the address.

Comment: "but nothing is said about what GCC thinks the pointer points to" The standard does not require an implementation to publish its thoughts about what the resulting pointer points to.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit then unless there is another section in the GCC documentation that elaborates on this, GCC is not fully conforming. Implementation-defined behavior must be documented. Definition: *"**implementation-defined behavior** unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made"*. Non-conformance here isn't really surprising, because compiler manuals are usually much less detailed and carefully designed than the standard documents. See https://www.iso-9899.info/n3047.html#3.4.1p1

Comment: The requirement is to specify the result of the conversion. GCC specifies every bit of the result, so that's done. There is no requirement to specify what can further be done with the result, or whether it points to anything (the standard itself says it doesn't have to point to anything).

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit a pointer consists of more than just an address. A pointer consists of a type, an address, and other provenance information such as whether it is a null pointer, a pointer to an object, a one-past-the-end pointer etc. I don't see why it would be valid for GCC to omit the last part. After all, a type and an address alone don't meaningfully describe what a pointer is.

Comment: The result of the conversion doesn't have to point to anything, so there is no requirement to document what it points to. Such a requirement would be impossible to fulfill anyway.

Comment: Regarding provenance, it is not "whether it is a null pointer" etc, it is pointer's *history* (how its value was obtained). The standard is extremely vague about pointer provenance (and different versions are vague in different ways). See [this](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2263.htm#q3.-can-one-make-a-usable-pointer-via-casts-to-intptr_t-and-back). AFAIK this is not a part of any standard (yet).

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit: Provenance was formerly part of the standard, but the verbiage of "safely-derived" got removed.

Comment: @BenVoigt That was in C++, no?

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit: Correct, the word "C++" was missing from preceding comment.  (It seems really unlikely for C to standardize something which C++ had and removed.  The languages don't make all the same decisions but overall the language evolution tends to be in the same direction.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it UB to compare pointers casted from integers?

Yes.  The cast itself risk trouble<sup>*1</sup> and then the compare does also.

A *pointer equality compare*, `==`, `!=` is valid against valid pointers of the same type and null pointers.
[@Eric Postpischil
1 hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76636354/is-it-ub-to-compare-pointers-casted-from-integers/76639999?noredirect=1#comment135122465_76639999) provides details.

---

To meet OP's larger objective, consider instead an alternative:  Create global `int` objects instead of `(int*)(0x80000000)` and `(int*)(0x12345678)`.

```
int pointer_test_something[42];
int pointer_test_bad;

#define POINTER_TO_SOMETHING (&pointer_test_something[0])
#define BAD_POINTER (&pointer_test_bad)

...

int *p = some_condition ? POINTER_TO_SOMETHING + 42 : BAD_POINTER;
if (p == BAD_POINTER) { ... }
```

---

<sup>*1</sup>  An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might produce an indeterminate representation when stored into an object. C23dr § 6.3.2.3 5

Comment: Re “A _pointer equality compare_, `==`, `!=` is valid against valid pointers and null pointers”: Where does the standard say that? The first three constraint options for `==` speak to types, not values, valid or not. The fourth involves a null pointer constant, which is not relevant here.  In the semantics, for pointers, it says “Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (… or function,…” and so on, none of which speak to “validity.” “If and only if” covers **all** cases…

Comment: … If the program has constructed a pointer by conversion from an integer in a defined way, then the pointer either points to the same object as another pointer or satisfies one of the other listed cases or it does not. Whether the pointer is “valid” does not come into play.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing any two pointers is well-defined (but maybe not meaningful, depending on system). The undefined behavior appears with pointer arithmetic.

Pointer arithmetic in C is defined by the additive operators (binary + and -).

C17 6.5.6 §8:

> If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

In your case, it is unknown to the compiler where the pointers point at. They do not point at an array, so it is undefined behavior.

However, embedded systems compilers that need to do pointer arithmetic outside arrays almost always implement non-standard extensions that guarantee well-defined behavior.

It may be safer and more sensible to cast to `uintptr_t` instead of a pointer and then do all arithmetic on that type, since it's a plain integer.

---

Do note that `((int*)(0x80000000))` is almost certainly always a bug though. This would have to be a `volatile` qualified pointer in most contexts. Check out [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: It's wrong to say that "they do not point to an array". It is implementation-defined whether the compiler considers them to point to an array. It's possible that an array exists at the address `0x80000000`, how do you know that it doesn't? And why would the compiler assume that there isn't?

Comment: @JanSchultke The compiler can only know of declared objects. If you pass it an absolute address, it is regarded as an object with no declared/effective type. The compiler generally has no clue about which addresses objects end up at: that's the linker's job.

Comment: Why would the compiler assume that there isn't an object which happens to have the address `0x80000000` somewhere else in the program, making this code valid? You seem to imply that almost all uses of pointers created from integers is UB basically, and that's just not how it works.

Comment: @JanSchultke It's a quality of implementation thing. The only reason why this is UB is because of various architectures with segmented memory maps. But most applications do not have that, so it doesn't make sense for them to make something UB that's well-defined in the hardware. But as far as the C standard can tell it is UB, because it knows nothing about addresses at all, only objects.

Comment: I would like to see a source on that. It seems like a gross violation of programmer intent to turn uses of pointers created from literal addresses into UB. I couldn't find anything in the compiler manual about uses of such pointers being UB, so for now, calling it UB is just hearsay.

Comment: @JanSchultke I already gave the most relevant source in the answer. The 6.3.2.3 parts are only concerned about the actual conversion itself and possible issues of alignment, they do not mention anything about usage of the result. 6.3.2.1 about lvalues explicitly labels a lvalue access which does not designate an object undefined behavior. Then there's the effective type/strict aliasing rules in 6.5, which address access of objects with no declared type. After such an access, the address is given an effective type. 6.5.6 §7 says that such an object is equivalent of an array with size 1.

Comment: That paragraph proves nothing. The question is what the compiler thinks `0x800000` means once converted to a pointer. A compiler could treat that conversion as implicitly beginning the lifetime of an array, if this leads to well-defined behavior for `p + 42`. Functions like `memcpy` has similar magical properties. Why do you insist that integer-to-pointer conversion is any different with **ZERO EVIDENCE**?

Comment: @JanSchultke I just listed the evidence. It's not my problem if you don't want to look it up. And I seriously doubt you could have done that in just 7 minutes unless you were already familiar with the referenced parts. Do I have zero evidence or is it you who is too lazy to look it up? Similarly `memcpy` is also covered by the mentioned 6.5 effective type rule.

Comment: You're just not getting it. The conversion from integers to pointers is implementation-defined, which gives the compiler a lot of freedom to make this well-formed. It could say that converting an integer to a pointer always produces a pointer to an object, which's lifetime implicitly begins on first use, if its lifetime hasn't begun yet, and has whichever type produces well-defined behavior. This can be defined as magically as necessary to make it well-defined, so any claim that this is UB without consulting the compiler manual is bogus.

Comment: @JanSchultke Again, the _conversion_, between integers and pointers, aka the act of changing a type between an integer and a pointer type, has in itself nothing to do with the access of the resulting object, nor with pointer arithmetic. The life time of objects has absolutely nothing to do with type conversions. As for the compiler manual, what part of _"However, embedded systems compilers that need to do pointer arithmetic outside arrays almost always implement non-standard extensions that guarantee well-defined behavior."_ was unclear?

Comment: I've already listed all the sources necessary in my answer, and have explained why this behavior can easily be well-defined. Even if it's UB to use the pointer *sometimes*, the explanation in your answer is wrong. You say *"They do not point at an array, so it is undefined behavior."*. It is still *possible* that the pointer points to an array, regardless of compiler magic, so your answer is simply wrong.

Comment: @PaulHankin that's only for relational comparisons though, not equality comparisons, as shown in OP's code. Equality-comparison is always well-defined, so the crucial question is whether `+ 42` is well-defined.

Comment: @PaulHankin Check out sentence 1 of this answer. I'm not sure who you are quoting with your comment?

Comment: The authors of the Standard may have intended that an equality comparison between any two valid pointers will never do anything other than yield 0 or yield 1, but the authors of clang and gcc seem to have other ideas.  This discrepancy has been reported on both compilers' bug-reporting systems, but I see no evidence that the authors of clang and gcc have any intention of matching the Standard-prescribed behavior.